# "navigator.msLaunchUri" in IE Edge always return success

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, protocols

"navigator.msLaunchUri" in IE Edge always return success  , 
"noHandlerCallback" is not executed 
I tried this :

```
navigator.msLaunchUri('App:123456',
function()
{
alert('success');
},
function()
 {
alert('failed');
}
);
```

It will always return "success" and if the protocol was not supported it will open the windows store dialog and return "success"

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that Edge behaves differently from IE11 in this regard. I am not sure if this exactly the same problem that you are experiencing but this is what I have seen.

If you register a protocol, launch it with IE11 and later unregister, Edge gets confused.

**Short Answer:**

Make sure that when you unregister your protocol, you completely remove the following registry keys if they exist:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myprotocol
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\myprotocol
```

**Long Answer:**

When you call msLaunchUri, IE11 looks at the first key above to determine if the protocol is registered, but Edge looks at both keys.

The first one is the key that you use to register the protocol, the second one is a key created by IE11 when you launch the protocol from it.

So if the user happens to launch the protocol with IE11, then unregister, Edge will get confused.

To make sure Edge does not get confused, remove all the keys completely.