# Cannot open office documents using msLaunchUri from Edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, document

I am trying to create a document explorer targeted for Edge. For that purpose I am using the msLaunchUri method as follows:

```
navigator.msLaunchUri('ms-word:ofe|u|http://docServerPath/someFolder/document.docx', function() { console.log("success")}, function() { console.log("error")});
```

However, the document is never opened. I've tried with different types of office documents, but the outcome is always the same. Is there a way to either fix this or to open the documents in a different way?

I am using Win10 and Edge 42.17134.1.0 (EdgeHTML 17.17134).

Comment: Do you try to execute the code from a user interaction or some other way? Browsers have mechanisms to try to prevent opening things when that was not requested by a user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the Edge 42 version environment, I have tested your code using Edge 44.18362.1.0 version and Edge 41.16299.1004.0 version, they all will open the documents,

I suggest you check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473198/navigator-mslaunchuri-in-ie-edge-always-return-success?rq=1), perhaps the issue is relate to the following registry keys, you could try to remove it.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myprotocol
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\myprotocol
```

If still not working, please try to [reset the browser setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10). Also, you could try to upgrade the browser version.